# How do I set *Iproj files to different targets?

Tags: swift, xcode, localization

I have `.rtf` documents that I want to use for different targets and languages. For example, I have structure like this:

```
en.Iproj
    File1.rtf
    File2.rtf
sv.Iproj
    File1.rtf
    File2.rtf
```

When I use English as the language the en.Iproj folder is used and when I use Swedish, the sv folder is used. The problem is that I want to use `File1` for prodoct `target` 1 and `File2` for `target` 2. But from what I can see I can only set the *.Iproj folders to different targets under `file inspector`. When I click `File1.rtf` or `File2.rtf` the option to set targets disappear.

So how do I go about making `File1.rtf` only available for `target1` and `File2.rtf` available for `target2`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and did not face any issue.

[image]
[image]

There might be some other issue, check my project from https://github.com/sauvikapple/LocationStackoverFlowAns-63246405.

Change language by editing target's scheme.
[image]